# How can I identify the brand name of bathtub?

Tags: bathtub

I need to replace the pump on my jetted tub and the plumber requests the brand name of the bathtub in order to do so. Where do I look to see if I can locate the brand name? This tub was possibly manufactured in the mid 1990s. I can upload a picture if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

There should be an access panel of some type, to get to the electrics. Start by looking within that compartment. At the very least, there should be a label on the motor (nameplate). If you send that information to the plumber, it should give them a clue.